# sonar.issue.ignore.allfile not working?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
SonarQube Server 6.7.1
SonarC# 6.7.1

I am trying to exclude files with a specific pattern, e.g. when I find a hint to a 3rd party contribution in a source.

I pass following parameters

- /d:sonar.issue.ignore.allfile=ExcludeStuff
- /d:sonar.issue.ignore.allfile.ExcludeStuff.fileRegexp="Vendor.*Name"

So I am seeking to catch all files that have "VendorName", "Vendor Name" or "Vendor     Name" in their content.

In the *SonarScanner end* step I get outputs like

```
INFO: '<filename...>' generating issue exclusions
```

for almost all files -- I have failed understand which files produce that output. I do not see a relation to the regex pattern.

Eventually the summary is always that all files are indexed and none are excluded.

So here are my specific questions:

1. How can I tell whether or not a files is excluded for all issues?
2. What is the correct syntax of the regex?
3. Is there a working example / documentation on the *sonar.issue.ignore.allfile* stuff?

I cannot use *sonar.exclusions* because due to the path structure I would need absolute paths which are -- for whatever reason -- not available in the scanner anymore.

I spent quite some time doing research on the *sonar.issue.ignore.allfile* usage without success. Perhaps I have missed it, but I would gladly take any advice.

Comment: You appear to have the right syntax, but exclusions are extremely tricky to set correctly via parameters. Have you tried setting your exclusion through the UI? Have you tried setting a regex of `.*` to see whether the problem is with the regex or the property syntax?

Comment: I have tried to set the parameter to ".*" in the UI: no success, I mean I would expect all my issues to be gone, right?
Is there a log where the processing of this option can be seen?